# Maintaining positioning on mobile/tablet (Responsive)

Tags: css, sass, flexbox, css-animations

I have a CSS animation on 3 boxes (Flexboxes) that transition from off screen to in position using transforms, however whenever I resize the window these boxes space out away from each other and move away from their intended positioning (they should be overlapping). How do I make these boxes stay in place? Or, if that is not possible, how can I remove the transforms to return them back to staying within one row but extending the full width of the screen ?

index.scss

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container > div {
  width: 30vw;
  height: 80vh;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: solid 2px black;
  &:nth-child(1) {
    animation-name: scrollinRight;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    background: red;
  }
  &:nth-child(2) {
    animation-name: scrollinTop;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    background: rgb(120, 107, 133);
    z-index: 2;
  }

  &:nth-child(3) {
    animation-name: scrollinLeft;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    background: green;
  }
}

@keyframes scrollinRight {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-100vh);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(100vh);
  }
}

@keyframes scrollinLeft {
  0% {
    transform: translate(100vh, 100vh);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(-100vh, 10%);
  }
}

@keyframes scrollinTop {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(100vh);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(5%);
  }
}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use percentage in your keyframes for the translateX

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/pf0kxzba/)

```
@keyframes scrollinRight {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(-100vh);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(150%);
  }
}

@keyframes scrollinLeft {
 0% {
    transform: translate(100vh, 100vh);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(-150%, 10%);
  }
}
```